# How do you reset the Github status checks?

Tags: github

The test suite that my Github status checks trigger didn't run when I initially opened my pull request. Is there a way to trigger this manually without committing more code?

Answer (score 17):

Update: you can also push an empty commit to your branch to re-trigger status checks: `git commit -m "retrigger checks" --allow-empty`

Try closing and re-opening your pull request to re-trigger status checks. If that fails, just create another pull request and close the old one.

Answer (score 8):

If you don't want to add empty commits, and if you are working alone in your own branch (see below), you could use the following trick: just perform a fake amend to the last commit, and do a force push.

```
git commit --amend --no-edit
git push -f origin your_branch
```

Obviously this will change (in theory, although not in practice) the commit history, so you should do this only in your own branch where you are the only committer (for instance when preparing a pull request from a forked repository to the upstream one).